# Writing PDF on local storage using JsPdf in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, jspdf

I am trying to write a html converted pdf file via jspdf but its not working here is the js method

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
        writer.truncate(11);
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {



            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
            writer.seek(4);var pdfOut;
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
        pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
        pdfOut = pdf.output('datauri');
                });
         // this alerts shows "Undefined"
        alert(pdfOut);
        writer.write(pdfOut);



            writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
            }
        };
    };
            var pdfOut;
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
        pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
        pdfOut = pdf.output('datauri');
                });
        // this alerts shows "Undefined"
            alert(pdfOut);
        writer.write(pdfOut);


}
```

Both alerts shows "Undefined".If I create it as **.txt** file it shows empty file and if i save it as **.pdf** if creates corrupted file. JsPdf is working fine because I can see **pdf.output('datauri');**'s result in base64 string on log...

Comment: can u share your tutorial which u followed i m using jspdf lib but its not generating pdf file

Comment: @Erum : I don't remember which tutorial I followed but the code in question works fine the trick is that you need to wait for addHTML method to perform its functionality and then write the pdf file. please refer to the accepted answer and my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addHTML call is async, so you have to wait for completion before trying to use the pdf output. Also, with a FileWriter an "arraybuffer" output is best suitable.

Try this:

```
    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
      writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
        console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
        // ...
      };
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
      pdf.addHTML(document.body, function () {
        writer.write(pdf.output('arraybuffer'));
      });
    }
```

Comment: that's rite I figured out the problem and used "setTimeout" to wait, but your approach looks much better.. thanks..